# Function to generate an array of random numbers with no repetitions

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm creating a function to generate an arry of random and not repeating numbers.What am i doing wrong?

With this code the function fills the array repeating some numbers.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          numero = random.nextInt(delta) + da;
          for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
            if(numero==estratti[j])
            {
              numero = random.nextInt(delta) + da;
              j=0;
            }        
          }
          estratti[i] = numero;
        }
```

Comment: Start by telling us what it's doing at all.

Comment: Just create an `Array` with the desired range and then shuffle it

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to occur if you randomly roll a duplicate number, then roll a new number, and randomly roll `estratti[0]`. You set `j=0` when you find a duplicate, but the next time you check whether `numero==estratti[j]` is in the next iteration of the loop. By then, `j` has been incremented `j++` to `1`, hence you miss this case.

To fix it, you could set `j = -1` if you find a duplicate number.

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage an hashset structure and do something like this untested java code:

```
HashSet set = new LinkedHashSet();
while (set.size() < n) {
    set.add(random.nextInt(delta));
}
return set.toArray();
```

The [`HashSet.add` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) will not add a value if it is already present.

Adapt that code to your situation.

Comment: While this generates unique random numbers, by doing `set.toArray` those numbers will be in sorted order (ordered by their hashcode, i.e. themselves). Better store them in a list or array and just use the set as a faster and more convenient way to check whether a number has already been rolled before.

Comment: You are right @tobias_k, a LinkedHashSet is in order here (keep the insertion order): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: But... no, the toArray will not return the generated numbers ordered by hashCode. They will be ordered according to the place they occupy in the backing array of linked list. Which is different than the insertion order but still just scrambled some more. You are mingling HashSet with SortedSet.